# Issue with camel ZipAggregationStrategy

Tags: apache-camel, camel-zipfile

I'm trying to zip all files in target folder into one zip archive via Camel v3.20.2.
I have tried example from documentation and it works. I see file `reports.zip` in the `output/directory`

```
from("file:input/directory?noop=true")
    .split(body())
    .aggregate(constant(true), new ZipAggregationStrategy())
    .completionFromBatchConsumer().eagerCheckCompletion()
    .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, constant("reports.zip"))
    .to("file:output/directory");
```

However I don't know the target directory so I will take it from the Exchange during runtime.
This is simplified example based on previous one:

```
from("direct:zip")
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            File srcFile = new File("path-to-target-folder");
            exchange.getIn().setBody(srcFile.listFiles());
        }
    }).split(body())
    .aggregate(constant(true), new ZipAggregationStrategy())
    .completionFromBatchConsumer().eagerCheckCompletion()
    .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, constant("reports-2.zip"))
    .to("file:output/directory");
```

I don't see file `reports-2.zip` in the `output/directory`. I have found zip file `camelxxxxxxxx.zip` in the `temp` folder. This zip archive is correct and contains files from target folder.
Why second example doesn't copy file to `output/directory`?